# Rails MongoDb has_many and embeds_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have the following table structure for example - Users, Projects.

Users has_many Projects
Projects has_many Photos

But i want to embedded certain basic content of Projects and Photos into the Users Table so that i can reduce the number of database calls for certain pages.

Below is the structure i have come up with.

**Users Table**

```
[
  {
    "id": "LONG-MONGO-ID-HERE-USER-1",
    "name": "Harsha MV",
    "email": "harsha@mink7.com",
    "gender": "male",
    "telephone": "9986377561",
    "is_pro": 1,
    "projects": [
      {
        "id": "LONG-MONGO-ID-HERE-PROJECT-1",
        "name": "Nike",
        "url": "http://nike.com",
        "logo": "logo_nike.jpg",
        "photos": [
          {
            "title": "Some title for an Image",
            "file": "project1_photo1.jpg"
          },
          {
            "title": "another title for an Image",
            "file": "project1_photo2.jpg"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "LONG-MONGO-ID-HERE-PROJECT-2",
        "name": "BMW",
        "url": "http://bmw.com",
        "logo": "logo_bmw.jpg",
        "photos": [
          {
            "title": "Some title for an Image",
            "file": "project2_photo1.jpg"
          },
          {
            "title": "another title for an Image",
            "file": "project2_photo2.jpg"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "LONG-MONGO-ID-HERE-USER-2",
    "name": "Pruthvi Gowda",
    "email": "pruthvi@mink7.com",
    "gender": "male",
    "telephone": "9982318016",
    "is_pro": 0,
    "projects": [
      {
        "id": "LONG-MONGO-ID-HERE-PROJECT-3",
        "name": "Adidas",
        "url": "http://adidas.com",
        "logo": "logo_adidas.jpg",
        "photos": [
          {
            "title": "Some title for an Image",
            "file": "project1_photo3.jpg"
          },
          {
            "title": "another title for an Image",
            "file": "project1_photo4.jpg"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "LONG-MONGO-ID-HERE-PROJECT-2",
        "name": "BMW",
        "url": "http://bmw.com",
        "logo": "logo_bmw.jpg",
        "photos": [
          {
            "title": "Some title for an Image",
            "file": "project2_photo1.jpg"
          },
          {
            "title": "another title for an Image",
            "file": "project2_photo2.jpg"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Projects Table**

```
[
    {
      "id": "LONG-MONGO-ID-HERE-PROJECT-1",
      "name": "Nike",
      "url": "http://nike.com",
      "logo": "logo_nike.jpg",
      "about": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
      "testimonial": "e middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend",
      "photos": [
        {
          "title": "Some title for an Image",
          "description": "um is simply dummy text of the printing and t",
          "file": "project1_photo1.jpg"
        },
        {
          "title": "another title for an Image",
          "description": "text of the printing and t um is simply dummy",
          "file": "project1_photo2.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "user": {
        "id": "LONG-MONGO-ID-HERE-USER-1",
        "name": "Harsha MV",
        "email": "harsha@mink7.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "LONG-MONGO-ID-HERE-PROJECT-2",
      "name": "BMW",
      "url": "http://bmw.com",
      "logo": "logo_bmw.jpg",
      "about": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the",
      "testimonial": "from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum",
      "photos": [
        {
          "title": "Some title for an Image",
          "description": "um is simply dummy text of the printing and t",
          "file": "project2_photo1.jpg"
        },
        {
          "title": "another title for an Image",
          "description": "text of the printing and t um is simply dummy",
          "file": "project2_photo2.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "user": {
        "id": "LONG-MONGO-ID-HERE-USER-1",
        "name": "Harsha MV",
        "email": "harsha@mink7.com"
      }
    }
  ]
```

As I have understood MongoDb is all about replication of data. is this the right way of designing the database structure.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String
  field :company_name, type: String


  embeds_many :projects, class_name: "Project"
  has_many :projects, class_name: "Project"

end
```

Can i do something like the above so that i can save two instance of the same data.
But as you see in the embedded document i am not storing all the data from the projects - how can i strict it from adding all the data as embedded document but stored as a separate table?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to add same model as both embedded and referenced collection. You can put the structure as same you have mentioned initially by referencing the project collection in user.

And create dummy model say `ImportantProject` which will be embedded in User and you can sync up the data project in this model while making changes in database.

Comment: you mean to say that i can only have references in the Users Table to Projects thru a dummy model?

Comment: no I am saying you can create has_many relation between User and Project but to save other data of Project, you can create a dummy model which will be embedded in User and you can save the data you required

Comment: my only concern is coming from SQL background. if i want to show a list of the users and title of the projects in a table. i make a call to the users. then i have to run a loop to again fetch content of all his project and build an object and then pass it on to the view. while in mysql we can just use join and do a single call. is this is how we can achieve it in NoSQL?

Comment: you can achieve these by writing your own code also but there is already good option available https://github.com/dzello/mongoid_alize it worked for me